# Use fetched data from Json for other Json parse

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch shows json data. If you paste the id after this url, there is more in depth information about the launch, for example https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch/2053.

I want to get the image url of the corresponding launch but it doesn't work how I'm doing it. This is the code from where I parse the JSON data.

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_launches, container, false);
        myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        launchesList = new ArrayList<>();
        temporaryList = new ArrayList<>();
        myRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        parseJSON();
        return v;
    }


    private void parseJSON(){
        String url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("launches");

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject launch = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String launchName = launch.getString("name");
                                String launchDate = launch.getString("net");

                                launchId = launch.getString("id");

                                String imageUrl = getImageUrl();



                                Launch newLaunch = new Launch(launchName, launchDate, imageUrl);
                                launchesList.add(newLaunch);

                            }

                            myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), launchesList);
                            myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
                            myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(LaunchesActivity.this);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        myRequestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public String getImageUrl(){
        String url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch/" + launchId;
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("launches");


                            JSONObject launch = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONObject rocket = launch.getJSONObject("rocket");
                            String url = rocket.getString("imageURL");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        myRequestQueue.add(request);
        return url;
    }
```

This is the adapter I created to change the text in the TextViews and ImageView.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{

private Context myContext;
private ArrayList<Launch> launchList;
private OnItemClickListener myListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    myListener = listener;
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Launch> launchList){
    myContext = context;
    this.launchList = launchList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.launch_item, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Launch currentItem = launchList.get(position);

    String name = currentItem.getName();
    String date = currentItem.getDate();
    String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageUrl();

    holder.myTextViewName.setText(name);
    holder.myTextViewDate.setText(date);
    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(holder.myImageViewImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return launchList.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView myTextViewName;
    public TextView myTextViewDate;
    public ImageView myImageViewImage;


    public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.launch_name);
        myTextViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        myImageViewImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(myListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        myListener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A launch object is just this:

```
public Launch(String name, String date, String imageUrl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Recyclerview item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#323131">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/launch_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Launch name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Recyclerview layout

```
Recyclerview layout:

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:background="#323131"/>
```

Comment: add the json object or json array to your question.

Comment: You mean like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make getImage function get the index of array object and i will tell you why

```
String imageUrl = getImageUrl(i);

public String getImageUrl(final int index)
```

after getting url adding that

```
String url = rocket.getString("imageURL");


 launchesList.get(index).imageUrl = url;
 myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
```

now i tell the thread of get image get image and when finish notify adapter
it work for me

[image]

Comment: please vote up answer to help other people to know the correct answer faster

Answer (score 0):

In your `getImageUrl()` you are returning the wrong url which is this:

```
    String url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch/" + launchId;
```

instead do this:

```
public String getImageUrl(){
    String url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch/" + launchId;
    //add this
     String imageURL = null;

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("launches");


                        JSONObject launch = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONObject rocket = launch.getJSONObject("rocket");
                        imageURL = rocket.getString("imageURL");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    myRequestQueue.add(request);
    //return it here
    return imageURL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't show a picture in my imageview.

Comment: is the first call working, I mean are you getting the id?

Comment: add a screen shot  of your json object that has the imageURL instead of what you did above, because it is very confusing to look at.

Comment: i have also tried to manually enter an image url in the imageUrl variable in the parseJSON() method and it still did not show the picture so maybe there is something wrong in the adapter or layout file?

Comment: are you able to log the imageURL.

Comment: what do you mean by that (i'm very new to android studio)

Comment: I mean are you getting an imageURL or not, is the variable null?

Comment: if no add a screenshot of your json data? The above is very confusing and messy.

Comment: i added a screenshot at the bottom of the JSONObject

Comment: i'm not getting an imageURL

Answer (score 0):

my friend above help u in parsing but let me know why you use two request one for parsing object and second one for get image but u should know that here you will use two thread so we will work on make them in one thread
and check if catch print any log
please send object in array to getImage function and continue to parse

```
String imageUrl = getImageUrl(launch );
```

and fix getImageUrl function

```
public String getImageUrl(JSONObject  launch ){

    JSONObject rocket = launch.getJSONObject("rocket");
    String url = rocket.getString("imageURL");
    return url;
}
```

try this if error still exist please inform me and i will try it on my code

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried it but unfortunatly it didn't seem to solve my problem

Comment: i will do it for you :) give me 5 minutes

Comment: send xml to test plz

Comment: Did you find solution :) ?